# How to set an incrementing flag column for related rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I am trying to create a flag column called "Related" to use in reporting to highlight specific rows that are related based on the ID column (1 = related, NULL = not related). The original table "table1" looks like below:

```
Name       ID         Related
--------------------------------
Jack       101        NULL
John       101        NULL
Pat        105        NULL
Ben        106        NULL
Jordan     106        NULL
George     300        NULL
Alan       500        NULL
Bill       200        NULL
Bob        200        NULL
```

I then used this `UPDATE` statement below:

```
UPDATE a
SET Related = 1
FROM table1 a
JOIN (SELECT ID FROM table1 GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b
ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Below is the result of this update statement:

```
Name       ID         Related
--------------------------------
Jack       101        1
John       101        1
Pat        105        NULL
Ben        106        1
Jordan     106        1
George     300        NULL
Alan       500        NULL
Bill       200        1
Bob        200        1
```

This gets me close but I need for it to instead of assigning the number 1 to each related row, to increment the number for each set of related rows based on their different ID column values.

Desired result:

```
 Name       ID         Related
    --------------------------------
    Jack       101        1
    John       101        1
    Pat        105        NULL
    Ben        106        2
    Jordan     106        2
    George     300        NULL
    Alan       500        NULL
    Bill       200        3
    Bob        200        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an updateable CTE - comments explain the logic.

```
with cte1 as (
    select [Name], ID, Related
        -- Get the count within the id partition, less 1 as specified
        , count(*) over (partition by id) - 1 cnt
        -- Get the row number within the id partition
        , row_number() over (partition by id order by id) rn
    from @Test
), cte2 as (
    select [Name], ID, Related, cnt, rn
        -- Add 1 *only* if the count is > 0 *and* its the first row in the id partition
        , case when cnt > 0 then sum(case when cnt > 0 and rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) else null end NewRelated
    from cte1
)
update cte2 set Related = NewRelated;
```

This doesn't assume `Related` is already `null` and works for more than 2 rows for any given ID.

It does assume that one can order by the `ID` column - even though the data provided doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution using `dense_rank` to number your related values and an updateable CTE

```
with r as (
    select id
    from t
    group by id having Count(*) > 1
),
n as (
    select t.id, t.related, Dense_Rank() over (order by r.id) r
    from r
    join t on t.id = r.id
)
update n set related = r
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that that assumes `Related` starts as `null`.

Comment: It does in the OP's sample data

Answer (score 2):

**You can do this without a self-join, just using window functions in a CTE, and updating the CTE directly:**

```sql
WITH tCounted AS (
    SELECT
      t.id,
      t.related,
      c = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY r.id)
    FROM t
),
tWithRelated as (
    SELECT
      t.id,
      t.related,
      rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY r.id)
    FROM tCounted
    WHERE c > 1
)
UPDATE tWithRelated
SET related = rn;
```

Comment: Nope.  This was my first thought as well, but the sequence would not be correct.

Comment: Righto, you need to filter before numbering. Have fixed. Still doesn't need a self-join though